# Зачем Room создаёт дополнительные таблицы базы данных?

Tags: android, sqlite, retrofit2, android-room, android-sqlite

Писал android приложение получающее данные с сервера с помощью `Retrofit` и заполняющее этими данными локальную базу данных.
Решил посмотреть на структуру базы данных (база данных создаётся автоматически на устройстве) в программе `DB Browser for SQLite` и обнаружил, что кроме таблиц, создающихся по классам `model` там есть ещё таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

класс базы данных:

```
@Database(entities = [CardModel::class, MedicationsModel::class, OrderLocalModel::class], version = 1)
abstract class DataBasePharmacy : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val cardDao: CardDao
    abstract val medicationsDao: MedicationsDao
    abstract val orderLocalDao: OrderLocalDao
}
```

классы из директории models:

CardModel:

```
@Entity(tableName = "card_data_table")
class CardModel (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_id")
    val id:Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_name")
    val name:String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_image")
    val image:String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_price")
    val price:String,
    // id товара, которое регулирует то, добавлен товар в корзину или нет
    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_idProduct")
    val idProduct:String,
    // колличество единиц товара
    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_count")
    val count:String,
    // итоговая цена
    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_total_price")
    val totalPrice:String
)
```

MedicationsApiModel:

```
data class MedicationsApiModel (
    @SerializedName("id") @Expose
    var id: Int? = null,
    @SerializedName("image") @Expose
    var image: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("name") @Expose
    var name: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("description") @Expose
    var description: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("price") @Expose
    var price: String? = null
)
```

MedicationsModel:

```
@Entity(tableName = "pharmacy_data_table")
class MedicationsModel (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pharmacy_id")
    val id:Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "pharmacy_name")
    val name:String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "pharmacy_image")
    val image:String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "pharmacy_description")
    val description:String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "pharmacy_price")
    val price:String

)
```

OrderLocalModel:

```
@Entity(tableName = "order_local_data_table")
class OrderLocalModel (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "order_local_id")
    val id:Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "order_local_nameUser")
    val nameUser:String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "order_local_phoneUser")
    val phoneUser:String,

    // описание заказа
    @ColumnInfo(name = "order_local_description")
    val description:String,

    // общая цена
    @ColumnInfo(name = "order_local_totalPrice")
    val totalPrice:String
)
```

OrdersApiModel:

```
data class OrdersApiModel (
    @SerializedName("id") @Expose
    var id: Int? = null,
    @SerializedName("name") @Expose
    var name: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("phone") @Expose
    var phone: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("description") @Expose
    var description: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("priceOrder") @Expose
    var priceOrder: String? = null
)
```

P.S. Собираюсь создавать приложение, где в базу данных, с одним заранее заполненным полем буду получать данные с помощью `Retrofit` для другого поля, однако, так как в этом случае базу данных я буду создавать вручную, опасаюсь, что из за отсутствия этих таблиц приложение не будет работать

Answer (score 1):

Это служебные таблицы Room, которые хранят мета данные о созданных таблицах

Comment: а если этих таблиц нет (к примеру, база данных создавалась вручную в директории `assets`), приложение не будет вылетать